# SQL Update on Duplicate key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In SQL Server, I have a table with just one primary key but I need to `Insert` or `Update` if a set of columns (non primary) exists.

I know about the `composed keys` - `multiple keys` on a table but I can not `alter` the table.

Is there a way to do it on a single query, maybe a variable of the `on duplicate key` functionality? or should be resolve on several queries?

For example:

Table_Name: `Contacts`

Columns:

```
id (int) PK
Name (vc30)
usrName (vc20)
Email (vc30)
Pass (vc15)
otherUsrData (...)
```

The constraint should be `(usrName,Email)`

You can have the same `usrName` with different `emails` each or different `usrName` with the same `email` (I know that sounds illogic but it's just an example)

```
1 - usr1 - email_A@example.com - textA
2 - usr1 - email_B@example.com - textA
3 - usr2 - email_A@example.com - textA
4 - usr2 - email_B@example.com - textA
```

So a new record is generated with `usr2` and email `email_C`, I insert it on the table, because the combination (`user2`,`email_C`) doesn't exist.

But if it's `usr2` with `email_B`, then I will update `textA` to `textB` because there exists a record with a combination (`user2`,`email_B`)

Comment: Do you want to add a constraint that combination of (UserName, Email) is always unique? Or do you want to invoke a trigger to do some action, if combination of (UserName, Email) is duplicated?

Comment: "update the table to add constraint"  = "alter", but you cannot alter. Not sure what you are wanting

Comment: I can not alter/modify the table configuration like add rows, keys, change the column type. I can only insert, select, update or delete records.

Comment: Can you add triggers to the table?

Comment: If you don't have permission to alter table, then you cannot do any of these... you need to ask someone to give you permission, or ask them to alter the table for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `MERGE`-statement

```
DECLARE
  @usrName varchar(20)='usr1',
  @Email varchar(30)='email_A@example.com',
  @Pass varchar(15)='111';

-- update test
MERGE Contacts trg
USING
  (
    SELECT
      @usrName NewUsrName,
      @Email NewEmail,
      @Pass NewPass
  ) src
ON trg.usrName=src.NewUsrName AND trg.Email=src.NewEmail

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    trg.Pass=src.Newpass

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT(usrName,Email,Pass)
  VALUES(src.NewUsrName,src.NewEmail,src.NewPass);

SELECT *
FROM Contacts;


SET @usrName='usr1';
SET @Email='QQQ@example.com';
SET @Pass='222';

-- insert test
MERGE Contacts trg
USING
  (
    SELECT
      @usrName NewUsrName,
      @Email NewEmail,
      @Pass NewPass
  ) src
ON trg.usrName=src.NewUsrName AND trg.Email=src.NewEmail

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    trg.Pass=src.Newpass

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT(usrName,Email,Pass)
  VALUES(src.NewUsrName,src.NewEmail,src.NewPass);

SELECT *
FROM Contacts;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an unique index on the key column(s) with the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option set to on. This will result in the duplicate rows being ignored during the INSERT operation for instance. You will have to however update the rows by inserting into another table and then performing update
2. Use a worktable approach where you insert all the rows into the worktable and then use insert/update as into the main table.